# C/C++ Better way to write this?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to write easy to debug code. Is there a better way to write the function `do_save()`:

```
int one;
int two[10];
char three;

...

unsigned char *state = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024);

...

void do_save()
{
    memcpy(state, &one, 4);
    memcpy(state+4, two, 40);
    memcpy(state+44, &three, 1);
}
```

When I say better I mean a way to avoid creating bugs because I messed up the size counting, especially when there are 10 or 20 variables to be saved in state.

Comment: `sizeof(int)`(or `sizeof(one)`) and multiplication... btw `std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> state = new unsigned char[1024];` might be better

Comment: Is the C++ tag intended? The code seems entirely C-minded

Comment: I added c++ in case someone knows a better solution in c++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a struct.

```
int one;
int two[10];
char three;
typedef struct {
    int one;
    int two[10];
    char three;
} State;

...

State *state = new State; // C++ish
State *state = malloc(sizeof(State));  //Cish

...

void do_save(State* state) {
    state->one = &one;
    memcpy(state->two, &two, sizeof(state->two));
    state->three = three;
}
```

There are lots of things you can do easily once you have a struct.  For instance, you can keep your current state and saved state separate and save/restore can be accomplsihed with an equal sign.  Writing to a binary file is easy with fread/fwrite.  You can put your state struct on the heap or on the stack, depending on your needs.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int one;
    int two[10];
    char three;
} State;

void print_state(State* state) {
    printf("%i ",   state->one);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        printf("%i ",   state->two[i]);
    }
    printf("%c\n",  state->three);
}

int main() {
    State* state = (State*)(malloc(sizeof(State)));
    State current_state;
    FILE* input = fopen("binary.data", "rb");
    if (input) {
        fread(&current_state, sizeof(State), 1, input);
        fclose(input);
    }

    print_state(&current_state);

    current_state.one = 1;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        current_state.two[i] = i + 1;
    }
    current_state.three = 'Z';
    *state = current_state;

    FILE* output = fopen("binary.data", "wb");
    fwrite(state, sizeof(State), 1, output);
    fclose(output);
        free(state);
}
```

Comment: Since that's a plain old value struct, a single `memcpy` for the whole thing would suffice

Comment: The reason I stored everything is a char* is to be able to store this char* in the hdd.

Comment: @Luka You don't need to copy data into a char* before writing it to disk.

Comment: @K-ballo since it's a plain old value struct, the built in operator= would also suffice ( the compiler will probably use memcopy to implement it, but may not if there is a more optimal manner )

Answer (score 2):

You could use variable to do the work for you.  For example:

```
int sizetotal = 0;
int sizethis = 0;

sizethis = sizeof(one);
memcpy(state+sizetotal, &one, sizethis);
sizetotal += sizethis;

sizethis = sizeof(*two);
memcpy(state+sizetotal, two, sizethis);
sizetotal += sizethis;

sizethis = sizeof(three);
memcpy(state+sizetotal, &three, sizethis);
sizetotal += sizethis;
```

As you can see the 3 lines are repeated -- so it could be put in a macro or function.

Of course if this is C++ the best thing to do would be to create a State object and give it appropriate methods.

Comment: `sizethis = sizeof(*two);` That produces 4 instead of the desired size, 40. He's trying to store the entire array.

Comment: @bames53 hard to tell the type of two from the code -- my code was intended as a guildeline not a solution -- thus the use of "example".

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are copying form consecutive offsets from the buffer state to some other locations. You could copy from consecutive offset to consecutive offsets by simply using a Struct -> like so:

```
typedef struct {
    int one;
    int two[10];
    char three;
} Container;

Container  my_storage

...
unsigned char *state = (unsigned char*)malloc(1024);
...

void do_save(Container  *dest, char*src) {
   memcpy(src, state, sizeof(Container));    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using C++:

```
    int one;
    std::array<int, 10> two;
    char three;

    std::vector<unsigned char> state(1024);

    auto start = state.begin();
    auto end = start + sizeof(one);
    std::copy(start, end, &one);

    start = ++end;
    end += two.size();
    std::copy(start, end, two.begin());

    start = ++end;
    end += sizeof(three);
    std::copy(start, end, &three);
```